# opencv findContours, contourArea value not consistant

Tags: opencv, contour, area

I have a test image (see the 1st image below), and a very simple code to blur and make canny edge detection of this image, then use findcontours to get contours.

```
image = cv2.imread("testimage.jpg")
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (11,11), 0)
cv2.imshow("Blurred", blurred)
canny = cv2.Canny(blurred, 50, 130)
cv2.imshow("Canny", canny)

(_, conts, _) = cv2.findContours(canny.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
img = image.copy()
for c in conts:
  M = cv2.moments(c)
  cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
  cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
  cv2.drawContours(img, [c], -1, (0,255,0), 1)
  cv2.putText(img, "area:"+str(cv2.contourArea(c)), (cX-20,cY-20),
          cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 2)

  cv2.imshow("Contours", img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I put the value of each contour on the image. As you may see, the contours look similar, but there is one contour with area value extremely low (only 16.0).

What might be the reason for this? And how to get consistent values among these contours?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the documentation on [contourArea](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga2c759ed9f497d4a618048a2f56dc97f1): _Thus, the returned area and the number of non-zero pixels, if you draw the contour using `drawContours` or `fillPoly`, can be different._ We encountered that problem in our projects, and therefore wrote a small method, that draws the filled contours on a blank image, and count the non-zero pixels. Cumbersome, but only intuitive way - from our point of view - to get a proper contour area.

Comment: @HansHirse Thank you for your immediate help. You mean "draws the filled contours on a BLACK image" ?

Comment: Yes, black image. I meant blank image as in empty image.

Comment: @HansHirse Thanks again. I am still quite new to opencv. Can you give a mini example on how to "fill" the contour to the blank image ?

Comment: Please have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga746c0625f1781f1ffc9056259103edbc) of `drawContours`. Or, look at [this](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html) Python tutorial.